# JSON TO CSV WITH JQ PLAY ERROR

Tags: command-line, csv, json

I am new to this. Please forgive me. I am trying to make a CSV file from JSON data. I got far but my data is complex.

I am using this line:

```sh
jq --raw-output '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv'
```

then I get this error in Jq Play:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:567): array ([{"Alternat...) is not valid in a csv row
"AlternateReferences","ArchiveSizeCode","AspectRatio","BarcodeId","Collections","ColorAppearanceId","Concepts","ContainsClippingPath","ContentWarnings","ContractId","CopyrightRegistrationEffectiveDate","CopyrightSubmitDate","CorbisId","CreditId","DatePhotographed","DisplayLocationConceptId","EmbargoDate","ExpirationDays","FineArtCopyrightStatusId","GroupLabels","ImageDisclosureStatusId","IngestSourceId","InputDate","IsForBillingOnly","IsInRFCD","IsInThemedImageSet","IsOriginalCaption","IsOutline","IsRestrictedFineArt","IsRoyaltyFree","KeywordingStatusId","LicenseModelId","LicenseRevenueTotal","MarketingCollectionId","MediaId","MediaRatingId","MediaSets","MediaStateId","MediaUid","NetActiveRestrictions","NonApprovalMediaUsageTypes","Notes","NumberOfSales","OriginalImageFormatId","OriginalMetadatas","OutlineSessionUid","Personas","PhotographerName","PrimaryContentTypeId","PrimarySubjectId","ProductionSetId","ProductionShoots","PublishedDate","ReleaseStatusSummaries","Releases","Renderings","RepresentationRightsId","Restrictions","SalesDetails","SearchableExternal","SearchableInternal","SecondaryContentTypes","SecondarySubjectId","SelectedByMemberUid","SelectedDate","SelectionStatusId","Source","Title","Type","ViewLevelId","WaitingForReplacementFile"
exit status 5
```

Thanks in advance....The data is below:

```json
[
{
  "ArchiveSizeCode": 558,
  "AspectRatio": "1.450144",
  "BarcodeId": 1102871,
  "ColorAppearanceId": 702,
  "ContainsClippingPath": false,
  "DatePhotographed": "2001-04-03T00:00:00",
  "FineArtCopyrightStatusId": null,
  "ImageDisclosureStatusId": null,
  "Type": 1,
  "CorbisId": "42-15278620",
  "ContractId": 52433,
  "CreditId": 1,
  "EmbargoDate": null,
  "ExpirationDays": null,
  "CopyrightRegistrationEffectiveDate": null,
  "CopyrightSubmitDate": null,
  "IngestSourceId": 2,
  "IsForBillingOnly": false,
  "OriginalImageFormatId": 15,
  "IsInRFCD": false,
  "PhotographerName": "Carole Bellaiche",
  "IsInThemedImageSet": false,
  "PrimarySubjectId": null,
  "IsRoyaltyFree": false,
  "SecondarySubjectId": null,
  "IsRestrictedFineArt": false,
  "DisplayLocationConceptId": 89958,
  "IsOriginalCaption": false,
  "Renderings": [
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "8bf9442f-2eda-469d-b39e-09966b8adfc4",
      "SizeCodeId": 71,
      "Volume": "corbis-collection-master",
      "VolumeTypeId": 53,
      "Path": "cleaned",
      "FileName": "4f64d1f6-9ddd-47b1-b2ec-1019e75e5e75.tif",
      "PixelHeight": 3470,
      "PixelWidth": 5032,
      "BitDepthId": 32,
      "ColorSpaceId": 2,
      "FileSize": 12516594,
      "FileFormatId": 49,
      "CompressionTypeId": 255,
      "FileModifiedAt": "2016-03-04T02:46:05",
      "FlavorId": null,
      "RenderingRoleId": 102,
      "IsVirtual": false,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": true
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "d75b268f-feaa-4cbc-b215-349e57e56d18",
      "SizeCodeId": 559,
      "Volume": "corbis-fulfillment-master",
      "VolumeTypeId": 53,
      "Path": "renderings/4f64d1f6-9ddd-47b1-b2ec-1019e75e5e75",
      "FileName": "42-15278620_559.jpg",
      "PixelHeight": 3470,
      "PixelWidth": 5032,
      "BitDepthId": 32,
      "ColorSpaceId": 2,
      "FileSize": 5630721,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": "2016-07-03T03:59:03",
      "FlavorId": 4,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": false,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": true
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "60701f7c-ae6b-4bb5-abef-7b3786c50fa2",
      "SizeCodeId": 67,
      "Volume": "\\\\Symdfs02\\Root\\S26",
      "VolumeTypeId": 24,
      "Path": "\\15\\27\\86",
      "FileName": "42-15278620.gqi",
      "PixelHeight": 441,
      "PixelWidth": 640,
      "BitDepthId": 32,
      "ColorSpaceId": 2,
      "FileSize": 78891,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": "2005-05-25T08:26:37",
      "FlavorId": 4,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": false,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": false
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "ce3d786f-980d-4494-adb4-8ba61d9c10e4",
      "SizeCodeId": 66,
      "Volume": "\\\\Symdfs02\\Root\\T26",
      "VolumeTypeId": 24,
      "Path": "\\15\\27\\86",
      "FileName": "42-15278620.gni",
      "PixelHeight": 176,
      "PixelWidth": 256,
      "BitDepthId": 32,
      "ColorSpaceId": 2,
      "FileSize": 34079,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": "2005-05-25T08:26:40",
      "FlavorId": 4,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": false,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": false
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "767075c9-7821-493e-91c6-be71d870a05d",
      "SizeCodeId": 72,
      "Volume": "corbis-collection-master",
      "VolumeTypeId": 53,
      "Path": "raw",
      "FileName": "4f64d1f6-9ddd-47b1-b2ec-1019e75e5e75.tif",
      "PixelHeight": 3470,
      "PixelWidth": 5032,
      "BitDepthId": 32,
      "ColorSpaceId": 2,
      "FileSize": 12521300,
      "FileFormatId": 49,
      "CompressionTypeId": 255,
      "FileModifiedAt": "2016-01-14T01:13:43",
      "FlavorId": null,
      "RenderingRoleId": 101,
      "IsVirtual": false,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": true
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "6d89ef22-d97b-45d2-b592-cc56dbddadd0",
      "SizeCodeId": 572,
      "Volume": "\\\\Symdfs02\\Root\\FS33\\Clear2",
      "VolumeTypeId": 24,
      "Path": "\\15\\27\\86",
      "FileName": "15278620.jpg",
      "PixelHeight": 276,
      "PixelWidth": 400,
      "BitDepthId": 32,
      "ColorSpaceId": 4,
      "FileSize": 17708,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": "2006-04-14T11:58:49",
      "FlavorId": 4,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": false,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": false
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "d1a215af-e72a-4eaf-a81e-cca774bf04bb",
      "SizeCodeId": 64,
      "Volume": "\\\\Symdfs02\\root\\FS51",
      "VolumeTypeId": 24,
      "Path": "\\Md\\15\\27\\86",
      "FileName": "42-15278620.jpg",
      "PixelHeight": 883,
      "PixelWidth": 1280,
      "BitDepthId": 32,
      "ColorSpaceId": 2,
      "FileSize": 244376,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": "2005-05-25T08:26:46",
      "FlavorId": 4,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": false,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": false
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "021683df-991d-4b55-b254-febb1a8220ef",
      "SizeCodeId": 561,
      "Volume": "\\\\symdfs02\\root\\FS71",
      "VolumeTypeId": 24,
      "Path": "\\Hi\\15\\27\\86",
      "FileName": "42-15278620.jpg",
      "PixelHeight": 1655,
      "PixelWidth": 2400,
      "BitDepthId": 32,
      "ColorSpaceId": 2,
      "FileSize": 1049509,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": "2006-04-14T11:58:44",
      "FlavorId": 4,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": false,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": false
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "12d0fbaa-fee6-4635-8ba3-a69d6e22373b",
      "SizeCodeId": 67,
      "Volume": "\\\\Symdfs02\\Root\\FS16\\Screen",
      "VolumeTypeId": 24,
      "Path": "\\15\\27\\86",
      "FileName": "15278620.jpg",
      "PixelHeight": null,
      "PixelWidth": null,
      "BitDepthId": null,
      "ColorSpaceId": null,
      "FileSize": null,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": null,
      "FlavorId": 1,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": true,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": false
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "16424340-33eb-402a-bbf1-8bc350eb5ec2",
      "SizeCodeId": 67,
      "Volume": "\\\\Symdfs02\\Root\\FS17\\Print",
      "VolumeTypeId": 24,
      "Path": "\\15\\27\\86",
      "FileName": "15278620.jpg",
      "PixelHeight": null,
      "PixelWidth": null,
      "BitDepthId": null,
      "ColorSpaceId": null,
      "FileSize": null,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": null,
      "FlavorId": 2,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": true,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": false
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "36dfa6a5-b310-4887-8007-d63a50709d48",
      "SizeCodeId": 67,
      "Volume": "\\\\Symdfs02\\Root\\FS18\\Clear",
      "VolumeTypeId": 24,
      "Path": "\\15\\27\\86",
      "FileName": "15278620.jpg",
      "PixelHeight": null,
      "PixelWidth": null,
      "BitDepthId": null,
      "ColorSpaceId": null,
      "FileSize": null,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": null,
      "FlavorId": 3,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": true,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": false
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "31bf14a1-a989-4df7-8dba-2fe24f568cd7",
      "SizeCodeId": 572,
      "Volume": "\\\\Symdfs02\\Root\\FS32\\Print2",
      "VolumeTypeId": 24,
      "Path": "\\15\\27\\86",
      "FileName": "15278620.jpg",
      "PixelHeight": null,
      "PixelWidth": null,
      "BitDepthId": null,
      "ColorSpaceId": null,
      "FileSize": null,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": null,
      "FlavorId": 2,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": true,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": false
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "944628ef-026e-43c7-aa31-a92d856d76a4",
      "SizeCodeId": 66,
      "Volume": "\\\\Symdfs02\\Root\\FS20\\Printlet",
      "VolumeTypeId": 24,
      "Path": "\\15\\27\\86",
      "FileName": "15278620.jpg",
      "PixelHeight": null,
      "PixelWidth": null,
      "BitDepthId": null,
      "ColorSpaceId": null,
      "FileSize": null,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": null,
      "FlavorId": 2,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": true,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": false
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "95d100b7-05ce-4305-8b13-db7368899a12",
      "SizeCodeId": 64,
      "Volume": "\\\\Symdfs02\\Root\\FS19\\1280DM",
      "VolumeTypeId": 24,
      "Path": "\\15\\27\\86",
      "FileName": "15278620.jpg",
      "PixelHeight": null,
      "PixelWidth": null,
      "BitDepthId": null,
      "ColorSpaceId": null,
      "FileSize": null,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": null,
      "FlavorId": 2,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": true,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": false
    },
    {
      "ImageRenderingUid": "30808732-0a61-4f6a-a252-61692af051f2",
      "SizeCodeId": 64,
      "Volume": "\\\\Symdfs02\\Root\\FS19\\1280WM",
      "VolumeTypeId": 24,
      "Path": "\\15\\27\\86",
      "FileName": "15278620.jpg",
      "PixelHeight": null,
      "PixelWidth": null,
      "BitDepthId": null,
      "ColorSpaceId": null,
      "FileSize": null,
      "FileFormatId": 61,
      "CompressionTypeId": 47,
      "FileModifiedAt": null,
      "FlavorId": 1,
      "RenderingRoleId": 103,
      "IsVirtual": true,
      "IsDerived": false,
      "RequiresProcessing": false
    }
  ],
  "IsOutline": false,
  "LicenseModelId": 1,
  "LicenseRevenueTotal": null,
  "MarketingCollectionId": 131,
  "MediaId": 15278620,
  "MediaRatingId": 261,
  "MediaStateId": 4,
  "MediaUid": "4f64d1f6-9ddd-47b1-b2ec-1019e75e5e75",
  "NonApprovalMediaUsageTypes": 0,
  "NumberOfSales": null,
  "OutlineSessionUid": null,
  "PrimaryContentTypeId": 682,
  "ProductionSetId": null,
  "PublishedDate": "2006-04-14T11:57:59",
  "RepresentationRightsId": 1,
  "SearchableExternal": false,
  "SearchableInternal": false,
  "SelectedByMemberUid": "0557644d-282a-42f0-b4ec-526a54308865",
  "SelectedDate": "2005-04-28T09:08:27",
  "SelectionStatusId": 1,
  "Source": "Sygma",
  "Title": "French Actress Dominique Blanc",
  "ViewLevelId": 0,
  "WaitingForReplacementFile": false,
  "KeywordingStatusId": 2,
  "AlternateReferences": [
    {
      "AlternateReferenceTypeId": 8,
      "AlternateReferenceId": "0000378238"
    }
  ],
  "Concepts": [
    {
      "ConceptId": 4416,
      "RelevancyId": 2
    },
    {
      "ConceptId": 5160,
      "RelevancyId": 1
    },
    {
      "ConceptId": 11268,
      "RelevancyId": 2
    },
    {
      "ConceptId": 11302,
      "RelevancyId": 2
    },
    {
      "ConceptId": 15102,
      "RelevancyId": 2
    },
    {
      "ConceptId": 26531,
      "RelevancyId": 2
    },
    {
      "ConceptId": 32403,
      "RelevancyId": 2
    },
    {
      "ConceptId": 36344,
      "RelevancyId": 2
    },
    {
      "ConceptId": 42696,
      "RelevancyId": 2
    },
    {
      "ConceptId": 89958,
      "RelevancyId": 2
    },
    {
      "ConceptId": 131592,
      "RelevancyId": 3
    }
  ],
  "Collections": [
    {
      "CollectionId": 25,
      "IsManual": false,
      "IsStatic": false,
      "IsForSearchFilter": true
    },
    {
      "CollectionId": 28,
      "IsManual": true,
      "IsStatic": false,
      "IsForSearchFilter": false
    }
  ],
  "ContentWarnings": [],
  "GroupLabels": [
    {
      "GroupLabelUid": "4f5f654c-a79b-49db-aeb5-e6beaadf3b4a",
      "GroupLabelTypeId": 2
    }
  ],
  "MediaSets": [],
  "NetActiveRestrictions": [
    {
      "RestrictionId": 109,
      "RestrictionUserId": 348
    },
    {
      "RestrictionId": 205,
      "RestrictionUserId": 118
    },
    {
      "RestrictionId": 292,
      "RestrictionUserId": 349
    },
    {
      "RestrictionId": 1587,
      "RestrictionUserId": 349
    },
    {
      "RestrictionId": 1886,
      "RestrictionUserId": 349
    },
    {
      "RestrictionId": 58206,
      "RestrictionUserId": 118
    },
    {
      "RestrictionId": 58671,
      "RestrictionUserId": 118
    }
  ],
  "Notes": [
    {
      "NoteUid": "e8d51899-8485-48e4-8249-6b79a28473c2",
      "QueueFunctionId": 2,
      "NoteAuthor": "Michaelle Gocko",
      "NoteText": "BA83272 (141 images):\r\n42-15280678\r\n42-15280669\r\n42-15280606\r\n42-15280607\r\n42-15280610\r\n42-15280609\r\n42-15280608\r\n42-15280619\r\n42-15280616\r\n42-15280618\r\n42-15280617\r\n42-15280622\r\n42-15280620\r\n42-15280623\r\n42-15278494\r\n42-15278495\r\n42-15278497\r\n42-15278496\r\n42-15278498\r\n42-15278499\r\n42-15278500\r\n42-15278501\r\n42-15278502\r\n42-15278504\r\n42-15278507\r\n42-15278506\r\n42-15278510\r\n42-15278511\r\n42-15278508\r\n42-15278512\r\n42-15278515\r\n42-15278516\r\n42-15278514\r\n42-15278513\r\n42-15278517\r\n42-15278521\r\n42-15278522\r\n42-15278520\r\n42-15278519\r\n42-15278518\r\n42-15278523\r\n42-15278524\r\n42-15278526\r\n42-15278527\r\n42-15278525\r\n42-15278528\r\n42-15278529\r\n42-15278530\r\n42-15278531\r\n42-15278532\r\n42-15278533\r\n42-15278534\r\n42-15278535\r\n42-15278536\r\n42-15278538\r\n42-15278537\r\n42-15278539\r\n42-15278540\r\n42-15278541\r\n42-15278542\r\n42-15278544\r\n42-15278543\r\n42-15278545\r\n42-15278546\r\n42-15278547\r\n42-15278549\r\n42-15278548\r\n42-15278550\r\n42-15278551\r\n42-15278552\r\n42-15278553\r\n42-15278554\r\n42-15278555\r\n42-15278557\r\n42-15278556\r\n42-15278558\r\n42-15278559\r\n42-15278560\r\n42-15278561\r\n42-15278563\r\n42-15278562\r\n42-15278564\r\n42-15278565\r\n42-15278568\r\n42-15278567\r\n42-15278566\r\n42-15278570\r\n42-15278569\r\n42-15278571\r\n42-15278573\r\n42-15278572\r\n42-15278574\r\n42-15278575\r\n42-15278577\r\n42-15278576\r\n42-15278578\r\n42-15278579\r\n42-15278580\r\n42-15278591\r\n42-15278581\r\n42-15278592\r\n42-15278593\r\n42-15278596\r\n42-15278595\r\n42-15278594\r\n42-15278598\r\n42-15278597\r\n42-15278599\r\n42-15278601\r\n42-15278602\r\n42-15278600\r\n42-15278604\r\n42-15278603\r\n42-15278605\r\n42-15278607\r\n42-15278606\r\n42-15278609\r\n42-15278608\r\n42-15278610\r\n42-15278611\r\n42-15278613\r\n42-15278614\r\n42-15278612\r\n42-15278617\r\n42-15278616\r\n42-15278615\r\n42-15278618\r\n42-15278620\r\n42-15278619\r\n42-15278622\r\n42-15278621\r\n42-15278623\r\n42-15278624\r\n42-15278628\r\n42-15278625\r\n42-15278629\r\n42-15278630\r\n42-15278632\r\n42-15278633\r\n42-15278634"
    },
    {
      "NoteUid": "19ef9fe0-5d12-4ba0-a67c-bf5db44b9523",
      "QueueFunctionId": 5,
      "NoteAuthor": "Michaelle Gocko",
      "NoteText": "Please route this image along with the one below to Editing => Production Control => Paris => Indexing - Paris after QA : (131 images ; 7 other images will come later because need to be sent back to the outside lab for scanning and 1 image is killed because of missing neg)\r\n42-15278494\r\n42-15278495\r\n42-15278496\r\n42-15278497\r\n42-15278498\r\n42-15278499\r\n42-15278500\r\n42-15278501\r\n42-15278502\r\n42-15278504\r\n42-15278506\r\n42-15278507\r\n42-15278508\r\n42-15278510\r\n42-15278511\r\n42-15278512\r\n42-15278513\r\n42-15278514\r\n42-15278515\r\n42-15278516\r\n42-15278517\r\n42-15278518\r\n42-15278519\r\n42-15278520\r\n42-15278521\r\n42-15278522\r\n42-15278523\r\n42-15278524\r\n42-15278525\r\n42-15278526\r\n42-15278527\r\n42-15278528\r\n42-15278529\r\n42-15278530\r\n42-15278531\r\n42-15278532\r\n42-15278533\r\n42-15278534\r\n42-15278535\r\n42-15278536\r\n42-15278537\r\n42-15278538\r\n42-15278539\r\n42-15278540\r\n42-15278541\r\n42-15278542\r\n42-15278543\r\n42-15278544\r\n42-15278545\r\n42-15278546\r\n42-15278547\r\n42-15278548\r\n42-15278549\r\n42-15278550\r\n42-15278551\r\n42-15278552\r\n42-15278553\r\n42-15278554\r\n42-15278555\r\n42-15278556\r\n42-15278557\r\n42-15278558\r\n42-15278559\r\n42-15278560\r\n42-15278561\r\n42-15278563\r\n42-15278564\r\n42-15278565\r\n42-15278568\r\n42-15278570\r\n42-15278571\r\n42-15278572\r\n42-15278573\r\n42-15278574\r\n42-15278575\r\n42-15278576\r\n42-15278577\r\n42-15278578\r\n42-15278579\r\n42-15278580\r\n42-15278581\r\n42-15278591\r\n42-15278592\r\n42-15278593\r\n42-15278594\r\n42-15278596\r\n42-15278597\r\n42-15278598\r\n42-15278599\r\n42-15278601\r\n42-15278602\r\n42-15278604\r\n42-15278605\r\n42-15278606\r\n42-15278607\r\n42-15278608\r\n42-15278609\r\n42-15278610\r\n42-15278611\r\n42-15278612\r\n42-15278613\r\n42-15278614\r\n42-15278615\r\n42-15278616\r\n42-15278617\r\n42-15278618\r\n42-15278619\r\n42-15278620\r\n42-15278621\r\n42-15278622\r\n42-15278623\r\n42-15278624\r\n42-15278625\r\n42-15278628\r\n42-15278629\r\n42-15278630\r\n42-15278632\r\n42-15278633\r\n42-15278634\r\n42-15280606\r\n42-15280607\r\n42-15280608\r\n42-15280609\r\n42-15280610\r\n42-15280616\r\n42-15280617\r\n42-15280618\r\n42-15280619\r\n42-15280620\r\n42-15280622\r\n42-15280623\r\n42-15280678"
    },
    {
      "NoteUid": "93eec114-50a5-4380-a343-cbd09c76eec8",
      "QueueFunctionId": 2,
      "NoteAuthor": "Ken Johnston",
      "NoteText": "Changed to Publish Internal; Sygma Alpha Project - Ken Johnston"
    }
  ],
  "OriginalMetadatas": [],
  "Personas": [],
  "ProductionShoots": [],
  "Releases": [],
  "ReleaseStatusSummaries": [],
  "Restrictions": [
    {
      "MediaRestrictionUid": "e42bc0b3-dff3-4caf-923e-34be5852f66b",
      "MediaRestrictionTypeId": 1,
      "RestrictionId": 109,
      "RestrictionUserId": 348,
      "StartDate": "2013-05-31T01:43:11.097",
      "DurationDays": null
    },
    {
      "MediaRestrictionUid": "09f2517d-4f23-45d7-a882-6bd0b3d01c2b",
      "MediaRestrictionTypeId": 1,
      "RestrictionId": 205,
      "RestrictionUserId": 118,
      "StartDate": "2008-10-06T00:00:00",
      "DurationDays": null
    },
    {
      "MediaRestrictionUid": "15a95448-a51c-42a7-95ea-23651f937040",
      "MediaRestrictionTypeId": 1,
      "RestrictionId": 292,
      "RestrictionUserId": 349,
      "StartDate": "2005-04-28T09:08:26.657",
      "DurationDays": null
    },
    {
      "MediaRestrictionUid": "f027de39-ac74-4a6f-8a38-e677035fbf10",
      "MediaRestrictionTypeId": 1,
      "RestrictionId": 1587,
      "RestrictionUserId": 349,
      "StartDate": "2005-04-28T09:08:26.657",
      "DurationDays": null
    },
    {
      "MediaRestrictionUid": "762cefef-330d-4beb-806a-c1c5d862f9b4",
      "MediaRestrictionTypeId": 1,
      "RestrictionId": 1886,
      "RestrictionUserId": 349,
      "StartDate": "2013-05-31T01:43:07.393",
      "DurationDays": null
    },
    {
      "MediaRestrictionUid": "acd7db23-0e8a-4619-a06f-ed1ee453a9c7",
      "MediaRestrictionTypeId": 1,
      "RestrictionId": 58206,
      "RestrictionUserId": 118,
      "StartDate": "2013-05-31T01:42:56.853",
      "DurationDays": null
    },
    {
      "MediaRestrictionUid": "a7999406-b56e-4917-b8e2-d39fc8342183",
      "MediaRestrictionTypeId": 1,
      "RestrictionId": 58671,
      "RestrictionUserId": 118,
      "StartDate": "2013-05-31T01:43:02.813",
      "DurationDays": null
    }
  ],
  "SalesDetails": [],
  "SecondaryContentTypes": [
    {
      "ContentTypeId": 665
    }
  ],
  "InputDate": "2005-04-28T09:08:26.657"
}
]
```

Comment: This would be more suitable on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32960857/4970442)

Comment: Please add the CSV output you want, simply two rows